# Is there a matrix with this specific quadratic determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, determinants

We have $\det M=(a+b)(c+d)$ where 
$M=\begin{bmatrix}
 a& 0& -1& 0\\
 0& c& 0& -1\\
 b& 0& 1& 0\\
 0& d& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\det M'=(a'+b')(c'+d')$ where 
$M'=\begin{bmatrix}
 a'& 0& -1& 0\\
 0& c'& 0& -1\\
 b'& 0& 1& 0\\
 0& d'& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Is there a matrix $A$ with linears forms in $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d',\pm1,0$ as entries that somehow uses $M$ and $M'$ as building blocks that gives
$$
\det A =
(a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d')
$$
(if needed we can use other $\Bbb Z$ entries but I would prefer not)?

It is ok to modify $M$ and $M'$ and use certain auxiliary supporting matrices as long as some structure of underlying matrices involved is evident.

Determinant of the following matrix suffices.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&c\\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&c\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&d\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&d\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&c'\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&c'\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&d'\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&d'\\
-a&-b&-a&-b&-a'&-b'&-a'&-b'&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

So we know such matrices exist. However there is a certain trouble here because it needs us to expand the polynomial fully and write down the determinant. There is no intuition of using $M$ and $M'$ as a building block.

Comment: The query came from understanding formula complexity. Don't understand the meaning of this ridicule.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, so this is an honest question: do you require A to also be a 4 by 4 matrix, or can it be larger?

Comment: @YemonChoi I think it has to be larger. I think it has be be somewhere between linear and quadratically as large as the number of summations needed.

Comment: I actually suspect this is not possible, but I don't know how to prove that. It seems an interesting question to me, but maybe I missed something. I voted to reopen.

Comment: The more general question is:  Given matrices $M$ and $N$, when does there exist a matrix $P$ all of whose entries appear in $M$ and $N$ and such that $det(P)=det(M)+det(N)$ ?    Can you settle any non-trivial cases of this?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I think if I am right any polynomial can be expressed as determinant (and the size is the central issue as in permanent determinant case) and so $det(M)+det(N)$ should be representable as a determinant.

Comment: Did you look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05788 ? They might have a method for answering your question.